Estimation of pooled prevalence (with 95%CI) in imputed and weighted data in R
I am trying to estimate the prevalence of a binary variable "x" and its confidence interval after multiple imputations (using mice) and applying weights in R. I use Rubin's rules for the estimation, but I am unsure if I implemented them correctly.
#### Prevalence after imputation and weighting ####
# Calculate weighted proportions by imputation

estimate_prop_x <- imp_long %>%
  group_by(.imp) %>%
  summarize(
    prop = sum((x == 1) * weight) / sum(weight), # Weighted proportion
    .groups = "drop"
  )

# Compute overall combined statistics using Rubin's rules
estimate_mean_prop_x <- estimate_prop_x %>%
  filter(.imp > 0) %>% # Exclude the observed data with missing values
  summarize(
  mean_prop = mean(prop),
  var_intra = var(prop),
  U_bar = mean(var_intra),
  m = 15, # Number of imputations   
  B = sum((prop - mean(prop))^2)/(m-1),
  var_comb = U_bar + (1 + 1/m) * B, # Combined variance
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    # Calculate adjusted degrees of freedom
    df_adj = (m - 1) * (1 + (var_intra / ((1 + 1/m) * B)))^2,
    # Critical t-value for a 95% confidence interval
    t_value = qt(0.975, df = df_adj),
    # Calculate confidence interval limits
    conf_low = mean_prop - t_value * sqrt(var_comb),
    conf_high = mean_prop + t_value * sqrt(var_comb)
  )

# Display the results
print(estimate_mean_prop_x)

Thank you for your help
